# If URL Contains special characters redirect to given url using javascript

Tags: javascript

If the URL contains `` '!$^*+()%[]\\\';@{}|\"<>`~' `` these special characters redirect to given URL. I have done but it is not working for %64 , &48& like this:

```
window.onload = function()
{
    var url=location.href;
    var value1=url.search('iframe');
    var value2=url.search('script');
    var splChars = '!$^*+()%[]\\\';@{}|\"<>`~';

    if((value1!= -1)||(value2!= -1))
    {
        window.top.location.href="www.sample.com";
    }

    url=url.replace(/%20/g," ");

    for (var i = 0; i < url.length; i++)
    {
        if (splChars.indexOf(url.charAt(i)) = -1)
        {
            window.top.location.href="www.sample.com";
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: why don't decode it? decodeURI()

Answer (score 0):

can you please try this regex

```
url=url.replace(/\`|\~|\!|\@|\#|\$|\%|\^|\&|\*|\(|\)|\+|\=|\[|\{|\]|\}|\||\\|\'|\<|\,|\.|\>|\?|\/|\""|\;|\:|\s/g," ");
```

Comment: No, Its not working.. am new to this. can u explain me clearly.

Comment: use regex for special charecters. if your string match with the regex then it will replace in to " ".

Comment: can you try this regex `\`|\~|\!|\@|\#|\$|\%|\^|\&|\*|\(|\)|\+|\=|\[|\|\]|\}|\||\\|\'|\<|\,|\.|\>|\?|\/|\"|\"|\;|\]|\{|\:|\s`

Comment: Thanks @ sangram bandi. but i dont wamt to replace with space. instead i have to replace with some sample url

Comment: what is the meaning of your code `url=url.replace(/%20/g," ");` ?

Comment: it just for space... i need to redirect when special characters or special character along with numbers occur in url..